# Making an Async HTTPGet class

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, androidhttpclient

I am trying to retrieve a string from a server using HTTPGet, then I want to set that string to a TextView in my MainActivity class. Here is the class I am trying to use to accomplish this. (I didn't include the imports here, but they are in the actual class. I also withheld the URL I am using here, but the actual URL is in my class)

```
public class GetFromServer {

public String getInternetData() throws Exception {
    BufferedReader in = null;
    String data = null;
    try{
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        URI website = new URI("URL withheld");
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
        request.setURI(website);
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
        String l = "";
        String nl = System.getProperty("line.separator");
        while ((l = in.readLine()) !=null){
            sb.append(l + nl);
        }
        in.close();
        data = sb.toString();
        return data;
    }finally {
        if (in != null){
            try{
                in.close();
                return data;
            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Then to use it in my MainActivity class:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

    GetFromServer test = new GetFromServer();
    String returned = null;
    try {
        returned = test.getInternetData();
        textView.setText(returned);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

This doesn't work because I get the `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException`, which means I have to use an AsyncTask. What I am asking is how do I turn this class into an AsyncTask so that it will work? Once it is an AsyncTask, how do I use it in my MainActivity class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a pretty thorough explanation of AsyncTask over at the [developer documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

Basically, you subclass AsyncTask, defining the types of parameters you will be working with. Your HTTPGet code will go into the `doInBackground()` method. To run it, you create a new instance of your AsyncTask class and call `execute()`.

Comment: I managed to make the class in an AsyncTask class. I can see when debugging the app that the string I want is being returned. Now I need to get the returned string into my MainActivity class so I can set the TextView to the string that is returned. How would I do this?

Comment: In the constructor of your AsyncTask, pass a reference to your Activity and store it in a field. Then you can call a public method of that Activity from `onPostExecute()`, passing the string as a parameter.